# Darboux's Theorem and Kahler manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Suppose that $(M,g,J)$ is a complex manifold such that $g$ is a Hermitian metric. Then the Kahler form can be written 
$$\omega = i \sum_{j,k} g_{j \bar{k}}dz^j \wedge d \bar{z}^k$$

However,  $\omega$ is also a symplectic form. Then shouldn't Darboux's theorem imply that there is a coordinate chart $U$ so that 
$$\omega|_U= i \sum_{j =1}^m dz^j \wedge d \bar{z}^j$$

However, this would imply that every Kahler manifold is locally flat which is certainly false. I think I am misunderstanding what vector space $\omega$ is supposed to be a symplectic form for. Can somebody explain why Darboux's theorem doesn't seem to apply even though $\omega$ is a symplectic form for $M$?

Comment: You're assuming that Darboux coordinates are holomorphic. They need not be.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ahh, obviously. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I do know it'a s 4-years-old comment...but could you explain a little more? The $z^j$s seem holomorphic...

Comment: @LoScrondo: Darboux's Theorem states that there is a coordinate chart $(U, (x^1, y^1, \dots, x^n, y^n))$ with $\omega|_U = dx^1\wedge dy^1 + \dots + dx^n\wedge dy^n$. *If* $x^k$ and $y^k$ were the real and imaginary parts of the holomorphic coordinate $z^k$, then we would have $\omega|_U = \frac{i}{2}(dz^1\wedge d\bar{z}^1 + \dots + dz^n\wedge d\bar{z}^n)$, but there is no reason why this would be the case.